# Is IF(ISSET necessary when already set REQUIRED?

Tags: php, html

I have an educated guess, and I need to either confirm it or discard it.

**GUESS**: When I am coding a form and the associated file that receives its data, it would be equivalent to:

- Use the `required` attribute in the `<input>`s of the form that I
  consider mandatory, and not set `if(isset(...))` in the file that
  receives the data.
- Don't use the `required` attribute in the form, but then do use `if(isset(...))`.

Because simultaneously using `required` and the `if(isset(...))` would simply be redundant (yet assuring I suppose).

**EDUCATED**: I have only seen the `if(isset(...))` trick in posts no newer than 2009, or in more recent ones that do rely on HTML5 tags at all. Whereas I have checked that the `required` attribute is in fact an HTML5 tag. Moreover, I recently took a web programming course that rapidly introduced HTML just to move to HTML5, and the 'HTML5-minded' instructor never used `if(isset(...))` when filling the data was a must, she just put `required` to the `<inputs>`.

So, I am right from a technical standpoint, in that both alternatives will do the same?

I provide examples below.

**FIRST ALTERNATIVE:**

In `send.php`:

```
<form action="receive.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="something" required />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In `receive.php`:

```
$name=$_POST['something'];
```

**SECOND ALTERNATIVE:**

In `send.php`:

```
<form action="receive.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="something" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In `receive.php`:

```
if(isset($_POST['something'])) {
$name=$_POST['something']; }
```

Comment: In your First Alternative: if you call `receivce.php` directly, `$_POST['something']` will not be set. Only if your form is being submitted.

Comment: You're right, they are *nearly* the same and this is extremely valuable during validation. You still need to validate what you have received on the server-side. CAVEAT: if you use JavaScript to perform the submission it *could* bypass any form directive.

Comment: Who said `receive.php` will receive information only from your carefully crafted HTML5 form? One can use `curl`, `wget`, a browser (or browser extension), a program (written in PHP/Perl/Python/any language) or even a plain `telnet` session to post data to it. Be prepared to parse and validate any kind of input in `$_POST[]`.

Comment: never trust client side validation.

Comment: _“and the 'HTML5-minded' instructor never used `if(isset(...))` when filling the data was a must, she just put `required` to the `<inputs>`”_ – well then she might be one of those naive people that assume every request that reaches their server-side script must have come from a “browser”.

Comment: [**Reiterating this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105783/is-ifisset-necessary-when-already-set-required/29105935#comment46441629_29105783)

Comment: @IkoTikashi indeed, that has been already worked upon in another part of the code. I am only interested in this right now.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard could you provide an example? I haven't got to JS yet. Thanks

Comment: @axiac I will investigate curl, wget and telnet to learn what you are talking about. Thanks for the info

Comment: @itachi please expand your point. Thanks

Comment: @CBroe I'll be more careful in the future, could you please explain what you meant in the end with the "browser" remark? Thanks

Comment: _Anything_ that “speaks” HTTP can be used to send requests to your script – it doesn’t have to be a browser, or to even know the concept of HTML and its `required` attribute.

Comment: @Berni excluding `curl`, `wget`, suppose i am using a browser which doesn't support _required_ tag.what will you do? or i manipulated the form before sunmitting via javascript or just removing the tag.... all your valiadation wil be out of the window in each case.

Comment: A couple of examples have been given @Berni, including the ability to disable the required function in the browser's console. A click function can be used to get the value of the inputs regardless of their attributes and properties. Here is a [slightly convoluted example](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/9u181xh2/). Without entering any information into the form click the 'submit' button. No value was set prior to form submission, yet a value would have been passed to the server, bypassing the 'required' property all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it's required. (depending)

Things to take into account;

**Will clients will always use the form**

You're assuming that your clients will always use the form in a GUI. What happens if - for some reason - someone sends a `curl` request and doesn't supply all the information (for example, if you have a public API - or a malicious hacker wants to get past all your client-side security checks).

**Errors will become apparent**

The only thing worse than Internet Explorer (Sorry Microsoft) is seeing and using a broken product. What if you miss-spell a `$_POST` key? Perhaps some errors will be displayed to a user (depending on your error reporting and settings)

**It's good habit**

Getting into good habit is *good*. You're requiring on front-end to send you the data and only that (see point 1). What if - somewhere further in your code - you're using a variable that is only set within an `if()` statement and you don't use `isset()` and your application breaks - or costs you money?

Checking something exists will *sometimes* lead you to check its contents and not blindly use it - ie: data sanitization and validation. This is very good practice to help protect yourself from bad data, attempted hacks, and other things.

---

#### Edits

> I have only seen the if(isset(...)) trick in posts no newer than 2009, or in more recent ones that do rely on HTML5 tags at all.

Please change the places you frequent to look at code. Also, never just use something "because I've not seen it being used on site x for a while".

> I recently took a web programming course that rapidly introduced HTML just to move to HTML5, and the 'HTML5-minded' instructor never used if(isset(...)) when filling the data was a must, she just put required to the .

You should challenge her on this. Give your teacher the link to this post if needed - but *always* check something exists before using it - we live in a dynamic internet age and websites are crawling websites, posting to other websites... interaction. If you need something from a client (end-user) **always check they provided it**.

**Look at it at another viewpoint**

- `required` HTML5 tag is for user experience. They don't need to press a button to find out "oh, I forgot this field" - or look for additional red asterisk (`*`) on your form.
- `isset()` in PHP will *check* that data was supplied by the client. A client can send data to your application in multiple ways - your front-end GUI is not the only way.

I've probably rambled on for quite some time about one function in PHP, but it could be handy to know others that check for existence;

- [isset()](http://php.net/isset)
- [array_key_exists()](http://php.net/array_key_exists)
- [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array)
- [defined()](http://php.net/defined)

*There are too many to list* - but I think you get the point. ***Always check something exists before using it, especially if it's from an unreliable source - such as a public facing front-end that anybody can manipulate***.

Comment: empty should be in the list imo.

Comment: @itachi "There are too many to list" - but feel free to edit my answer if you wish to contribute more functions to check existence :)

Answer (score 1):

2 problems for relying to client validation(required attribute)

**Client side valiadtion being bypassed:**

isset() on server is neccessary as required attribute can be **bypassed** by changing the html or many ways. For instance you can run an java script script or simply remove it from inspect element

running this on console will bypass it

```
document.getElementById("myinput").required = false;
```

**Request other than browser form/html:**

Secondly if you hit the page **directly** or with **curl,postman etc** you will get index not present error if you are not checking for isset()

Comment: Thanks, I will be more careful of security in the future because of this. I don't know what a curl or a postman is, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important distinction between client side and server side validations. The html5 `required` tag will prevent invalid requests sent in by the user, or whoever is using the front end. However, the front end is for example making this request

```
'example.com/index.php?something=123'
```

Nothing prevents a user from going to the javascript console or chrome's devtools or firebug and seeing exactly the api (php file) that the UI hits, and what request could be made to be potentially malicious by circumventing the UI. The attacker could simply hit this URL with other params, or other things that shouldn't be allowed, and if they hit it directly instead of through your UI, the client side validations do nothing. This is why you need both. I suggest looking into '[What are client side and server side validations](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/webdev/client-side-vs-server-side-validation-in-web-applications/)' to further your understanding.

Both 'methods' increase your security, but they don't protect against the same things.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do both, but you should definitely use if(isset()). Using devtools for example in Google Chrome I can remove "required" and submit the form empty. I can also add inputs, selects etc. Never rely on clientside.

Sanitization ... You want to clean the user input because it cannot be trusted. [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) etc.

Send

```
<form action="receive.php" name="SendForm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="something" />
<input type="submit" name="myForm" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Receive

```
if(isset($_POST['myForm'])) {
  $err = "";

  // get and sanitize post vars
  $var = some_type_of_sanitization($_POST['something']);
  $var2 = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['something2'])));

  // validate the values of vars
  if(empty($var)) { 
    $err .= "<li>This var is empty.</li>";
  }

  if (!empty($err)) {

    // display errors
    echo "<p>Errors:</p><ul>".$err."</ul>";

  }ELSE{

   // do something 

}else{

  // form wasn't submitted

}
```

Comment: I didn't know what to sanitize means and because of your answer I'll now do the research and learn a new thing. Thanks for the example, very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Required no, you dont need to use it. assuming you have errors set to no display on the server then the notices when its not been set will not be shown but they will likely be logged some place.

There are better methods of validating that make for a cleaner code over the procedural methods of if this then that etc etc.

Grab a copy of the PHP manual and read over it. For instance:

```
**filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'input field name', OPTION_VARS);**
```

See also **filter_vars()**.

Its also important that you do validate and/or sanitize the user input.

Javascript validation should only be used as a client side prop not as a server side validation.

IF somebody turned off javascript on their browser you would have zero validation and the form would submit.

If somebody duplicated that html5 form they could just remove the required attributes and again the form would submit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on the browser validation because there is no guarantee that the data you have in `$_POST[]` come from your carefully crafted form.

There are browser extensions that one can use to send whatever they want to your script. The browsers themselves can be used without extensions for that purpose (using their embedded Developer Tools).

One can use `curl`, `wget` or other HTTP client or download manager to access `receive.php`. Even a plain `telnet` session can be used by somebody that speaks `HTTP/1.1` to send bogus data to your script.

One can use PHP, Perl, Python and a dozen other languages to write a half-dozen lines of code script that sends data to your script.

I'll rephrase the first sentence of this answer: **You cannot rely on the browser validation** because there is no browser at the other end; and if there is a browser, you can't control it; you cannot tell it what to do.

#### What you *can* do:

You can write your PHP code to be able to handle *any* input it receives. For that you should work in two steps:

**Step 1**: Forget about the form. Write the PHP code and do not assume anything about the data you can get in `$_POST[]`. The only thing you can rely on is that `$_POST[]` is an array. It can contain anything; the values you expect to find in it can be there or not. Use `isset($_POST['something'])` and run all the validations you can think of on it. Write a basic form, don't use `required`, `readonly` or other HTML attributes that restrict the behaviour of the form elements. Don't put any Javascript on the form.

**Step 2**: After your PHP code is ready to handle any input, without relying on it already being validated or formatted in certain way and everything works correctly, start enhancing the behaviour of the form. Use `required`, `disabled`, `readonly` or other attributes you need. Use Javascript for validation, show/hide fields, animation, all you need/want.
**Don't** drop the validation on the server side.

The validation on the client side is for the customer. It provides a quick response and, if crafted carefully, it helps the customer to fill the form quickly and correctly.

The validation on the server side is for the application. It provides the first level defense against invalid or missing values, incorrect data types, inconsistent values a.s.o. It allows the rest of the application to work as expected without having to check every other line of code if the value is there and it is valid.